# How to get sqlalchemy length of a string column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider this simple table definition (using SQLAlchemy-0.5.6)

```py
from sqlalchemy import *

db = create_engine('sqlite:///tutorial.db')

db.echo = False  # Try changing this to True and see what happens

metadata = MetaData(db)

user = Table('user', metadata,
    Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String(40)),
    Column('age', Integer),
    Column('password', String),
)

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

class User(declarative_base()):

    __tablename__ = 'user'
    user_id = Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String(40))
```

I want to know what is the max length of column name e.g. from user table and from User (declarative class)

```py
print user.name.length
print User.name.length
```

I have tried (User.name.type.length) but it throws exception

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "del.py", line 25, in <module>
    print User.name.type.length
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.6-py2.5.egg/sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 135, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'type'
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
User.name.property.columns[0].type.length
```

Note, that SQLAlchemy supports composite properties, that's why `columns` is a list. It has single item for simple column properties.

Comment: I'd like to read more about this but can't find reference to the `property` attribute anywhere in the official docs. Would someone be kind enough to post a link?

Comment: Here is the type it returns: http://sqlalchemy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orm/internals.html?highlight=strategizedproperty#sqlalchemy.orm.properties.ColumnProperty

but I would like to second @KomodoDave and wonder where the documentation is for the property and columns attributes. My coworkers and I have reservations about using undocumented functionality.

Comment: Looks like the link above has died. The new URL appears to be https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/internals.html#sqlalchemy.orm.ColumnProperty

Answer (score 3):

This should work (tested on my machine) :

```
print user.columns.name.type.length
```

Comment: + thanks it works, but my usecase was bit different , I am basically using declarative_base to define a User class, how can i get length from class, please see modified question

Comment: yes it throws exception 'AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'type'' update Question

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the class:

```py
TableClass.column_name.type.length
```

If you have access to an instance, you access the Class using the `__class__` dunder method.

```py
table_instance.__class__.column_name.type.length
```

So in your case:

```py
# Via Instance
user.__class__.name.type.length
# Via Class
User.name.type.length
```

My use case is similar to @Gregg Williamson
However, I implemented it differently:

```py
def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
    column = self.__class__.type
    if length := getattr(column, "length", 0):
        value = value[:length]
    super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting errors when fields were too big so I wrote a generic function to trim any string down and account for words with spaces.  This will leave words intact and trim a string down to insert for you.  I included my orm model for reference.

````
class ProductIdentifierTypes(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'prod_id_type'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column(String(length=20))
    description = Column(String(length=100))

def trim_for_insert(field_obj, in_str) -> str:

    max_len = field_obj.property.columns[0].type.length
    if len(in_str) <= max_len:
        return in_str
    
    logger.debug(f'Trimming {field_obj} to {max_len} max length.')
    
    trim_str = in_str[:(max_len-1)]
    
    if ' ' in trim_str[:int(max_len*0.9)]:
        return(str.join(' ', trim_str.split(' ')[:-1]))
    
    return trim_str

def foo_bar():
    from models.deals import ProductIdentifierTypes, ProductName
    
    _str = "Foo is a 42 year old big brown dog that all the kids call bar."
    
    print(_str)
    
    print(trim_for_insert(ProductIdentifierTypes.name, _str))
    
    _str = "Full circle from the tomb of the womb to the womb of the tomb we come, an ambiguous, enigmatical incursion into a world of solid matter that is soon to melt from us like the substance of a dream."
    
    print(_str)
    
    print(trim_for_insert(ProductIdentifierTypes.description, _str))```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).